# mass customization web app - performance issue

Tags: jquery, mysql, xml, flash, performance

I wanted to create something like zazzle.com or puma.jp/tribes ([see this SO post for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326522/something-like-zazzle-or-www-puma-jp-tribes)). Having a mass customization app can be causing heavy traffic and can be a memory eater. Especially if you are performing AJAX calls every few seconds. does it really matter, what programming language I choose? Flash and XML (and DB behind) or JQUERY and PHP (and DB behind)?

Is there some web app performance (by type) comparison tool out there?

thanks a lot again

Steilflug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client side platform chosen doesn't really matter for overall performance - Flash performance can be pretty bad, but that's all on the client side so doesn't affect the number of users your server can support. A flash only site is a bad idea for a lot of reasons, but server performance isn't one of them.

On the server side you will need a database and PHP or equivalent whatever you do - something has to generate the XML. The various platforms available do have different performance characteristics, but the dominant factor in performance is generally the structure of your database and the queries you run on it, which is platform independent.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the server load may be caused by the continuous server requests - assume you have 100 users at once, making server requests each 20-40 seconds. so this is not affecting the overall performance which can be summarized in client app loading/refreshing caused by server response delay?! 

thanks man

Comment: Right, but those requests will be the same whatever platform you use.  If the large number of requests is a problem you need to look at changing the system design, not the platform.

Incidentally, that example is only 5 requests per second, which is practically nothing for a modern webapp unless your system is really badly designed.